# Re-Exporting entire module in ES6/Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

Let's say I have a module I want to re-export:

```
//exportme.js
export default 'EXPORTME';
export const test = () => console.log('test function');

//reexport.js
export * from './exportme.js'
```

When I import reexport.js, the default from exportme.js is not available.

```
//app.js
import reexport from './reexport.js'

console.log(reexport) //undefined
```

I have to make reexport.js to be the following for it to work.

```
export * from './exportme.js'
export default from './exportme.js'
```

Is there an easier way to do this or can this be consolidated into one statement?

`export default, * from './exportme.js'` does not work.

I am using latest babel with `transform-export-extensions`

Comment: [Related Babel Github ticket](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2877)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The default from `exportme.js` is not available

Yes, default exports are not re-exported by star exports. The purpose of `export * from …` is to allow re-exports from multiple modules, exporting the `default` from multiple modules would only lead to collisions. You therefore have to specifiy it explicitly (if you need it at all, often there is no default export alongside named exports).

> Is there an easier way to do this or can this be consolidated into one statement?

No, the two lines you have are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As Bergi wrote, there is no way to do this in one line using ES 6 exports. You can, however, simply require the module you want to re-export and assign the result to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = require('./exportme.js')
```

Comment: This is clever and works. Unfortunately I'm trying to stick to not using require!